# How can a Transaction Guard make checks before a Safe transaction?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm exploring the possibilities given by Transaction Guards in a Safe. And I would like to understand better the concept of **Authorization before a Safe Transaction** (briefly described here https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5324092-what-is-a-transaction-guard )

My situation is the following:

- I want to create a Safe with other 3 friends (total user are 4)
- My 3 friends will be the 3 *Owners* of the safe (total signatures required 3/3)
- I would like to be *Transaction Guard* (my friends live in a different time zone and I can't approve transaction fast enough. But I want to be able to block their transaction in case the amount or destination wallet are not correct. I will automate this process so I don't need to be on a 24/7 watch)

I envision the flow like in this picture
[image: flow example]

I would like to understand if:

1. my understanding of the Transaction Guard role is correct. Can this
   flow be created?
2. the initiator of the transaction is one of the *owners*, and my role as a *guard* is to authorize them to sign and send that transaction. Is this correct?
3. the authorization from the *Transaction Guard* is done by signing a smart contract on the blockchain

Thanks for the help.